# Using Knapsack approach without value?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem

Regarding to  question, I am wondering that  according to the following approach:

Assume that there is no value and

I am wondering that which approach or algorithm should be used for a [Knapsack](https://ssaurel.medium.com/solving-the-knapsack-problem-in-java-c985c71a7e64) problem when the values are equal and there is a parameter (called n) that describes times for carrying items in a time?

For example, the bag has 3kg capacity and there are some blocks with the weight of 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2,75. Then we want to carry all the blocks with the minimum number of times (n). In this scenario, should I use Knapsack approach by giving value as 1. Or should I use completely another approach? Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean, you need to take `n` numbers of each item with a bag of capacity `m`? What is the quantity you are optimizing for? Complete as many `n` items as you can? Maximize the carried weight in the bag while respecting the max `n` of each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knapsack problem calculates maximum profit,So you obtain maximum number of times(n) if you assume all value as 1.
But if you set all values as -1 and find max profit, you can achieve your goal.

Comment: May there be completely another approach that is easier than Knapsack? Because as I do not need value parameter, it may be good idea to use a proper approach.

Comment: Think about that to be able to minimize n values, you should prioritize bigger weights. Values represent weight is exists or not.You can think this is as boolean value and has the same profit. Max profit value allows you to be sure of the optimal result. As for me Knapsack is proper way.